How do I transfer an SPL token in versioned transaction using web3.js
Trying to make spl-token transfer in a versioned transaction but can't find an example. The logs seem fine, but there are no actual transactions. I'm a newbie, don't be too hard on me please.

for (let recipient of recipients) {
    const recipientPublicKey = new web3.PublicKey(recipient.address);        

    const recipientTokenAccount = await splToken.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        senderWallet,
        tokenMintAddress,
        recipientPublicKey
    );

    try {
        const senderTokenAccount = await splToken.getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            senderWallet,
            tokenMintAddress,
            senderWallet.publicKey
        );
    
        const blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
        const instructions = [
            splToken.createTransferInstruction(
                senderTokenAccount.address,
                recipientTokenAccount.address,
                senderWallet.publicKey,
                BigInt(recipient.amount),
                [],
                splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
            )
        ];

        const messageV0 = new web3.TransactionMessage({
            payerKey: senderWallet.publicKey,
            recentBlockhash: blockhash.blockhash,
            instructions,
        }).compileToV0Message();

        const transaction = new web3.VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
        transaction.sign([senderWallet]);

        const txid = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction);
    }
}


Without any errors or sample transaction signatures, it's hard to see what's going wrong. Your code all looks correct from a quick glance
